# Set active class automatically to menu

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

Here I have create a simple menu by using php to to include that page. And I want to set active class to page that I am standing, but I don't how can do? 
this is my code:

```
<div class="top-nav">
    <div class="container">
        <span class="menu"> </span>
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="index.php?page=home">Home<span> </span></a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?page=collections">Collections<span> </span></a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?page=404">New Arrivals<span> </span></a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?page=404">Sale<span> </span></a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?page=404">Accessories<span> </span></a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?page=about">About Us<span> </span></a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?page=contact">Contact Us<span> </span></a></li>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for each menu you need to check the `$_GET['page']` if it the same with that page, than add a `class="active"` to the `li`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the active page variable before calling the header file that includes the navbar. note that each page will need a unique name to be referred to as the activePage.

```
<?php
    $activePage="home"; 
    $header = "includes/pageHeader.php";
    include($header);   
?>
```

and then in the nav menu for each li insert the php check as follows - if the activePage is the same as the check - it will add the active class to the li.

```
<li class="navLink <?php if($activePage == "home"){echo"active";}?>"><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
<li class="navLink <?php if($activePage == "aboutus"){echo"active";}?>"><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
etc....
```

and and so on through the rest of the links in the nav menu

Comment: A benefit of this is that you can use the same variable in the footer too - if you have navlinks in the footer - you can use the same logic to apply the class of active (and maybe have different css for the footer links) and therefore show the activePage at the top and bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
<li><a href="index.php?page=collections">Collections<span> </span></a></li>
```

become

```
<li<?= $_GET['page'] == 'collections' ? ' class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href="index.php?page=collections">Collections<span> </span></a></li>
```

Comment: This my session code :
    `<?php
      if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
       $page=$_GET['page'];
       $_SESSION['page']=$page;
      } else {
       $_SESSION['page']="home"; 
      }
  ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use `php_self` or `QUERY_STRING` for it

PHP:

```
  <? if(strpos($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], 'collections' ) !== false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need more details see that

```
<div class="top-nav">
<div class="container">
    <span class="menu"> </span>
    <ul>
        <li class="<? if(strpos($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], 'home' ) !== false) echo 'active';?>"><a href="index.php?page=home">Home<span> </span></a></li>
        <li><a class="<? if(strpos($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], 'collections' ) !== false) echo 'active';?>" href="index.php?page=collections">Collections<span> </span></a></li>
        <li><a class="<? if(strpos($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], '404' ) !== false) echo 'active';?>" href="index.php?page=404">New Arrivals<span> </span></a></li>
        <li><a class="<? if(strpos($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], '404' ) !== false) echo 'active';?>" href="index.php?page=404">Sale<span> </span></a></li>
        <li><a class="<? if(strpos($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], '404' ) !== false) echo 'active';?>" href="index.php?page=404">Accessories<span> </span></a></li>
        <li><a class="<? if(strpos($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], 'about' ) !== false) echo 'active';?>" href="index.php?page=about">About Us<span> </span></a></li>
        <li><a class="<? if(strpos($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], 'contact' ) !== false) echo 'active';?>" href="index.php?page=contact">Contact Us<span> </span></a></li>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

But you have more pages with same `page-404`